# inverted commas inside punctuation outside in biblatex-chicago

Tags: biblatex, csquotes

I write my PhD thesis using csquotes and opting for the British quotation style with  inverted commas and leaving punctuations outside. For example: Kant is nowadays considered the ‘*fondateur de discursivité*’ of modern Western cosmopolitanism.

However, biblatex-chicago, in the footnote citations and bibliography, uses the inverted commas outside the punctuation marks. For instance: Term used by Foucault in Michel Foucault, ‘Qu’est-ce qu’un auteur ?,’ in *Dits et Ecrits, tome 1 : 1954-1975*, ed. Daniel Defert and François Ewald (Paris: Gallimard, 2001 [1969-70]), 804.

Does anyone know how to set biblatex-chicago to automatically put the inverted commas inside the punctuation marks? Thank you in advance for your answer.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[style=british,autostyle=true,strict=true,english=british,autopunct=true,parthreshold=true]{csquotes}
\SetBlockThreshold{2}
 \usepackage{polyglossia}       
 \setdefaultlanguage[british]{english}
 \setotherlanguage{french}
\usepackage[notes,natbib,isbn=false,backend=biber,hyperref=true]{biblatex-chicago}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{MWE.bib}

@incollection{Foucault:2001qf,
    Address = {Paris},
    Author = {Michel Foucault},
    Booktitle = {Dits et Ecrits, tome 1 : 1954-1975},
    Editor = {Daniel Defert and Fran{\c c}ois Ewald},
    Pages = {789--821},
    Publisher = {Gallimard},
    Title = {Qu'est-ce qu'un auteur ?},
    Year = {2001 [1969-70]}}

@incollection{Flynn:2005rw,
    Address = {Cambridge},
    Author = {Thomas Flynn},
    Booktitle = {The Cambridge Companion to Foucault},
    Edition = {2nd},
    Editor = {Gary Gutting},
    Pages = {29--48},
    Publisher = {Cambridge University Press},
    Title = {Foucault's Mapping of History},
    Year = {2005}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\bibliography{MWE.bib}

\begin{document}
Kant is nowadays considered the `\textit{fondateur de discursivité}' of modern Western cosmopolitanism.\footnote{Term used by Foucault in \autocite[804]{Foucault:2001qf}.} He gave a definition of what he meant with `problematisation' in an interview:

\hyphenblockquote{british}{The ensemble of discursive and nondiscursive practices that makes something enter into the play of the true and the false and constitutes it an object of thought (whether in the form of moral reflection, scientific knowledge, political analysis or the like).\autocite[38]{Flynn:2005rw}}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Would you mind putting together a short MWE, so we can examine all the packages playing together *in situ*?

Comment: Unfortunately, `polyglossia` support ins `csquotes` isn't great "Note that `polyglossia` support is currently in a preliminary state because `polyglossia` is lacking a proper interface for other packages. In practice, this means that `csquotes` can detect the language (e.g., `english`) but not the language variant (e.g., `british`)." (p. 2, fn. 1 of the [`csquotes` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/csquotes/csquotes.pdf)). ...

Comment: ... While `biblatex` has been developed further with a better experimental `polyglossia` support, `csquotes` has been the same since 2011, and is therefore not able to deal with recent changes in `polyglossia`.

Comment: An easy fix would be to switch to `babel`. Both `biblatex` and `csquotes` work together very smoothly with `babel` and are in particular able to pick out the language variant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> **Update** Since this answer was written `csquotes` has been adopted by Joseph Wright and code has been added to both `biblatex` and `csquotes` to work together with `polyglossia`. This requires recent versions of all packages involved.
>
> The MWE should work as expected with `\setdefaultlanguage[variant=british]{english}` instead of `\setdefaultlanguage[british]{english}`.

While [`biblatex`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) is currently under active development, unfortunately [`csquotes`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/csquotes) has not been updated since 2011.

Recent versions of `biblatex` have received updates to support newer versions of `polyglossia` and the problems introduced by these changes (see for example [How to use polyglossia with biblatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/119682/35864)).

The [`csquotes`documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/csquotes/csquotes.pdf) states on page 2, footnote 1

> Note that `polyglossia` support is currently in a preliminary state
>   because `polyglossia` is lacking a proper interface for other
>   packages. In practice, this means that `csquotes` can detect the
>   language (e.g., `english`) but not the language variant (e.g., `british`).

That means, if you want to rely on `csquotes`'s `autostyle` option, you're better of using `babel`. Both `csquotes` and `biblatex` work very smoothly with `babel` (and pick up the language variant as well, not only the language).

Comment: I may end up having to 'pick up' both `etoolbox` and `csquotes`: someone probably will have to, and we need some stuff doing for `biblatex`!

Comment: Hooray for the update!  Chicago is just *wrong* (or at least seriously misguided) in this respect.  (This is not just personal opinion.  There are situations where placing quotes outside punctuation can cause hours of unnecessary extra work for tech support staff.)