# biblatex punctuation issue when book titles end in quotation marks

Tags: biblatex, citing, punctuation

1. The *Chicago Manual of Style* specifies American punctuation: periods and commas should precede closing quotation marks (§ 6.9).
2. It also specifies that titles within book titles should be enclosed in double quotation marks (§ 14.102).
3. Accordingly, some book titles will end in a closing double quotation mark.

Unfortunately, the `biblatex-chicago` package (and maybe `biblatex`) doesn't seem to have counted with the combination of rules 1 and 2 above. In the following minimal working example, the third citation results in a comma following the closing quotation mark, while the bibliography has a period following the closing quotation mark. Both should precede the closing quotation mark. How do I fix this?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{etex}
\usepackage{keyval}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[style=american]{csquotes}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[notes]{biblatex-chicago}

\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\begin{filecontents}{book.bib}
@book{key1,
   author = {Marty McFly},
   title = {This Book Title Ends in \enquote{Quotation Marks}},
   location = {Oxford},
   publisher = {Oxford University Press},
   year = {1976}
}

@book{key2,
   author = {John Updike},
   title = {Some Title},
   location = {Cambridge, MA},
   publisher = {Harvard University Press},
   year = {2002}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{book.bib}

\begin{document}

Here I cite a book whose title ends in a closing quotation mark\autocite[55]{key1}.
I follow this up with an unrelated citation\autocite[xi]{key2}.
Here I cite the first work a second time, which results in a short reference\autocite[75]{key1}, which unfortunately misplaces the period.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image: Footnote citation]
<sub>(source: [langeslag.org](http://langeslag.org/images/sx/cmspunctmwe1.png))</sub>

[image: Bibliographical entry]
<sub>(source: [langeslag.org](http://langeslag.org/images/sx/cmspunctmwe2.png))</sub>

The problem also occurs where my postnote ends in a closing quotation mark:

```
\autocite[s.v. ``word'']{dictionary}
```

but there I can hack my way through by adding a period inside the postnote itself.

Comment: Maybe rule #1 doesn't apply to bibliography entries, but just to ordinary sentences. Maybe the whole title, quotation marks included, should be seen as block or unit, in which case `biblatex-chicago` output would be right.

Comment: Have you tried using `csquotes` syntax for the quotation marks?

Comment: I hadn't! That sounds as though it ought to be the solution, but there's no difference yet. I'll add this to my original question--thanks!

Comment: Try `title = {This Book Title Ends in \mkbibquote{Quotation Marks}}` this will make your `.bib` file somewhat dependent on `biblatex` though.

Comment: See also [inverted commas inside punctuation outside in biblatex-chicago](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/151450/35864).

Comment: @moewe, that did the trick! Would you do the honours of upgrading your comment to an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `biblatex`/`csquotes` quotation command `\mkbibquote`.
So your example would look like this

```
title = {This Book Title Ends in \mkbibquote{Quotation Marks}}
```

This solution, unfortunately, comes at the cost of making the `.bib` file somewhat dependent on `biblatex`.

See also the advice in the [`biblatex-chicago` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-chicago/doc/biblatex-chicago.pdf) on pp. 49-50 about `\mkbibquote`, on p. 4 and actually quite a lot of other places (this is p. 4):

> [I]f you currently have quoted material in your `.bib` file, and are
>   using `\enquote` or the standard LaTeX mechanisms there, then the
>   simplest procedure is always to use `\mkbibquote` instead in order to
>   ensure that punctuation works out right.

MWE

```
\documentclass[american]{article}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[variant=american]{english}
\usepackage[notes]{biblatex-chicago}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{key1,
   author = {Marty McFly},
   title = {This Book Title Ends in \mkbibquote{Quotation Marks}},
   location = {Oxford},
   publisher = {Oxford University Press},
   year = {1976}
}
@book{key2,
   author = {John Updike},
   title = {Some Title},
   location = {Cambridge, MA},
   publisher = {Harvard University Press},
   year = {2002}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Here I cite a book whose title ends in a closing quotation mark\autocite[55]{key1}.
I follow this up with an unrelated citation\autocite[xi]{key2}.
Here I cite the first work a second time, which results in a short reference\autocite[75]{key1}, which unfortunately misplaces the period.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: As far as I can see, the only way to get this to work in a bibliography/citation context is to use `\mkbibquote`, as the "normal" `csquotes` commands do not work together with `biblatex`'s punctuation facilities. In order to improve portability, one might add `\providecommand{\mkbibquote}[1]{\textquote{#1}}` to the preamble if `biblatex` is not loaded.