# biblatex: mismatched quotation marks (italic/roman)

Tags: biblatex, punctuation

The *Chicago Manual of Style* says punctuation and quotation marks should match the surrounding rather than the enclosed font (i.e. roman or italic), unless they form part of a title, in which case they take on the font of the title (§§ 6.2, 6.5; cf. 14.102).

I take this to mean that in *Book Title "Including a Second Title,"* the opening and closing quotation marks should both be in italic. What to do with the comma is another issue.

Now, if I do exactly what the `biblatex-chicago` example bibliography does in this sort of situation -- i.e. format my bibliography in accordance with [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/195494/biblatex-punctuation-issue-when-book-titles-end-in-quotation-marks/195582#195582) --, I end up with an italic opening quotation mark and a roman closing quotation mark. It looks fine in the `biblatex-chicago` example PDF, but I suspect that's because the font used makes little or no difference between italic and roman quotation marks. When I recompile it with Computer Modern, I find it hard to tell a difference, again because it seems not to have very distinct italic quotes. But if I substitute the Cardo font, say, the closing quote is clearly roman where I imagine it should be italic like its peer.

XeLaTeX MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage[style=american]{csquotes}
\usepackage[notes]{biblatex-chicago}

\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Cardo}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\begin{filecontents}{book.bib}
@book{key1,
   author = {David Byrne},
   title = {This Book Title Ends in \mkbibquote{Quotation Marks}},
   location = {Oxford},
   publisher = {Oxford University Press},
   year = {2012}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{book.bib}

\begin{document}

Here I cite a book whose title ends in a closing quotation mark\autocite[55]{key1}.
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image: mismatched quotes]
<sub>(source: [langeslag.org](http://langeslag.org/images/sx/italicquote.png))</sub>

I've tried adding `\setpunctfont\emph`, but no difference. Any ideas?

Comment: This issue (and any proposed fix) should be reported to the package author.  But note that many of the packages listed are completely superfluous to the problem.

Comment: For future reference, please refer to questions that form the basis for your own question. An actual solution to your question here must rely on the information you provided [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/195494/biblatex-punctuation-issue-when-book-titles-end-in-quotation-marks), but you haven't mentioned that information in this question.

Comment: @PaulLangeslag You might want to retain `polyglossia` or `babel` though, as those two packages are not automatically loaded by `biblatex`. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: Mhhh, I could fix the problem for this particular case, but that solution will only work if you always have italic titles. I really feel that there should be a solution from the `biblatex` side. You might want to bring this issue up in the bug tracker: https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues.

Comment: Thanks -- I really appreciate your having had a go at this!

Comment: @moewe, I wonder if it's related to or at least similar to this issue: https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/499 Oh! Really old post! I missed that because it was edited…

Answer (score 3):

Your code is not particularly minimal, since most of the packages in your preamble have nothing to do with the problem you've identified.

When I put works with quotation marks in my `.bib` file, I've always just used the standard LaTeX method of typing `` and ''. That has always worked for me, and it works in this case, too. Why are you using \mkbibquote exactly?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
    \setmainfont{Cardo}
\usepackage[style=american]{csquotes}
\usepackage{biblatex-chicago}
\begin{filecontents}{book.bib}
@book{key1,
   author = {David Byrne},
   title = {This Book Title Ends in ``Quotation Marks''},
   location = {Oxford},
   publisher = {Oxford University Press},
   year = {2012}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{book.bib}

\begin{document}
Here I cite a book whose title ends in a closing quotation mark\autocite[55]{key1}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The reason for using `\mkbibquote` can be found in [biblatex punctuation issue when book titles end in quotation marks](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/195494/35864).

Comment: @moewe is right: the period should come before the closing quotation mark, and \mkbibquote takes care of that. The `biblatex-chicago` documentation also says to do it this way.

I included the packages in the preamble because these are listed as "required" (in some cases "recommended") at the top of the `biblatex-chicago` documentation, only I've substituted `polyglossia` for `babel`. But you're right, `verbatim` shouldn't have been in there -- my bad, I'll fix that.

Comment: @PaulLangeslag `biblatex` loads those required packages itself, so there is no need to do this on our own and clutter the MWE.

Comment: @PaulLangeslag And I doubt very much that ``biblatex-chicago`` recommends loading ``xltxtra``, since this package is no longer recommended for XeLaTeX. You should load ``fontspec``.

Comment: I believe this is a bug. You could get the italics by putting the title inside another set of braces: `title = {{Title with \mkbibquote{Quoted Portion}}},` But Chicago does require punctuation inside the quotation marks in every other case (it doesn't specify about book titles).

Comment: @AndrewCashner -- Chicago is simply following American typographical conventions, which always puts commas and periods inside quotation marks, unlike the 'British system', which does only includes the punctuation on the inside if it is part of the original quotation.